# Detecting multiple ellipses in an image of Python

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry, ellipse

Is there a way to detect multiple ellipses in an image in Python. I want to calculate the eccentricity and the circularity of the ellipse
I have tried multiple algortihms,

1. SimpleGlobdetector - this doesnt give any new values besides x, y and radius
2. FitEllipses - for some reason this doesnt work well
3. Hough_ellipses - this takes a lot of time for an image.

I want just a code to find the values I need for a class project. I have attached an example image, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried:

1. SimpleGlob detector and then keypoints from it
2. https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXB1O.png)

Comment: You could try OpenCV. Try this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-circles-and-ellipses-in-an-image-using-opencv-python/)

Comment: Realizing now that you tried SimpleGlob detector, not sure if you mean `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector`. I'm also not seeing an attached image

Comment: Sample imageS please.

Comment: "I want just a code to find the values I need for a class project": this certainly does not fit with this site's guidelines. We are not a coding factory, we do not do the homework for you.

Comment: @Modularizer I tried that article and you are right, it is cv2.SimpleBlobDetector. I am intersted to know whether I can find the values which it uses as filters, like inertiaRatio, Convexity etc. Do you think there is any way to obtain these values as return values for each ellipse it finds.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I defintely dont want anyone to do my class project. i can do that myself. I simply need a tip on one issue that I am having. I have updated a sample picture in the main text, I hope you can provide some help based on that.

Comment: These are circles. Circularity = 1 (or "perfect" value), eccentricity = 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have now updated the figure to reflect more ellipses. My goal was to provide a simple image so that I can get some tips for moving forward.

Comment: These drawings are not useful, we all know what an ellipse is. But real-life images are quite different and will require different processing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust if you can give me any tips with coding using this sample image, then it will be good. otherwise, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I observe that you don't believe me.